# Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'AIRPLANE_ID' is not a column in table

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ejb, derby

I'm working on a JavaEE application using EJB and JPA.

Here is my source:

### Flight entity:

```java
package com.airline.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Flight
 *
 */
@Entity
public class Flight implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Flight() {
        super();
    }

    @Id()
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FlightDestination flightdestination;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FlightDestination flightorigin;

    private Integer price;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date flighttime;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "airplane_id")
    private Airplane airplaneDetail;
    public Airplane getAirplaneDetail() {
        return airplaneDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Flight [id=" + id + ", flightdestination=" + flightdestination + ", flightorigin=" + flightorigin
                + ", price=" + price + ", flighttime=" + flighttime + "]";
    }

    // getters&setters
}
```

### Airplane entity:

```java
public class Airplane implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Airplane() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    private String planeMake;

    private String modelName;

    private Integer seatCapacity;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "airplaneDetail")
    private Flight flightDetail;

    //getters&setters
}
```

An error occurs while trying to add a flight. Here is the complete stacktrace:

```
2019-09-22T12:06:21.447+0530|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[com.airline.controllers.AddFlight]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.airline.controllers.AddFlight threw exception
javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:705)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4576)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2084)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2054)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:196)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:64)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy251.addFlight(Unknown Source)
    at com.airline.service.__EJB31_Generated__FlightService__Intf____Bean__.addFlight(Unknown Source)
    at com.airline.controllers.AddFlight.doGet(AddFlight.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:466)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:830)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:699)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'AIRPLANE_ID' is not a column in table or VTI 'ADMIN.FLIGHT'.
Error Code: 20000
Call: INSERT INTO FLIGHT (ID, FLIGHTDESTINATION, FLIGHTORIGIN, FLIGHTTIME, PRICE, airplane_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [6 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Flight [id=301, flightdestination=Dubai, flightorigin=Kochi, price=500, flighttime=Tue Jan 22 10:30:21 IST 2019])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl$1.handleException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:784)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.handleException(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:70)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:428)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'AIRPLANE_ID' is not a column in table or VTI 'ADMIN.FLIGHT'.
Error Code: 20000
Call: INSERT INTO FLIGHT (ID, FLIGHTDESTINATION, FLIGHTORIGIN, FLIGHTTIME, PRICE, airplane_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [6 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Flight [id=301, flightdestination=Dubai, flightorigin=Kochi, price=500, flighttime=Tue Jan 22 10:30:21 IST 2019])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2096)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:813)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2981)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1895)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1877)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1827)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1493)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1583)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:160)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'AIRPLANE_ID' is not a column in table or VTI 'ADMIN.FLIGHT'.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.prepareStatement(ConnectionHolder.java:562)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:231)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:28)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionImpl.prepareCachedStatement(ManagedConnectionImpl.java:968)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1544)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:628)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: ERROR 42X14: 'AIRPLANE_ID' is not a column in table or VTI 'ADMIN.FLIGHT'.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.prepareStatementX(Unknown Source)
    ... 83 more
```

Can please someone help me find what's wrong here?

Comment: Oops,my other entity is Airplane and the corresponding entity classpackage com.airline.models;


public class Airplane implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 public Airplane() {
  super();
 }

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name = "id")
 private Integer id;

 private String planeMake;

 private String modelName;

 private Integer seatCapacity;
 
 @OneToOne(mappedBy="airplaneDetail")
 private Flight flightDetail;

Comment: already edited your question to make it more readable :)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the error stacktrace, if you look closely to the causing exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'AIRPLANE_ID' is not a column in table or VTI 'ADMIN.FLIGHT'.
```

In your *Flight* entity it looks like you are trying to join by AIRPLANE_ID:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "airplane_id")
```

But there are no fields with that name in the *Airplane* entity.

This is why you are getting this exception.

In case you are trying to join with *id* field in *Airplane* entity class you should specify this in *Flight* entity:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
```

Or don't specify a *@Joincolumn* name attribute at all (JPA will use the default *@Id* field in the *Airplane* entity).

Hope this solves your problem.